# In how many ways can we draw 3 different cards from a deck of 52 cards, where the order in which cards are drawn doesn’t matter?

Tags: combinations

[image]

please refer the image if my answer is correct

Comment: A good way for you to settle the question is to work it for a smaller deck.  Suppose there are only $4$ cards in the deck.  What's the answer?  What does that tell you?

Comment: @lulu is 52C3 is correct or 52C3*(1/6)

Comment: I understand that you just want someone to hand you the answer, but try my example.  That one is small enough to work by hand.

Comment: thanks, @lulu I think I figured it out There are 4C3 ways to choose which suit goes first and stuff so that's 4.

Comment: Exactly!.  In this case, $\binom 43$ isn't even divisible by $6$.  In general $\binom nk$ refers to exactly what you want, the number of ways to choose an unordered subset from $n$ distinct objects.

Comment: are all distinguishable ?

Comment: thank u very much @lulu so NONE of the above is the answer

Comment: No...look at your example and read my comments.  For $n=4, k=3$ you got $\binom 43$.   If you are still confused, work the same problem with $n=5$.  And study the definition of the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing 3 from 52 is $\binom{52}{3}$. Given that $3!=6$, it sounds like you're thinking of dividing by $3!$ in order to ensure order doesn't matter. However, the $3!$ division is already included in $\binom{52}{3}$: $\binom{52}{3} = \frac{52!}{3!49!} = \frac{\frac{52!}{49!}}{3!}$. The numerator $\frac{52!}{49!}$ is actually $P(52,3)$, choosing $3$ from $52$ when order matters.

It seems like what you intended was to choose $\frac{P(52,3)}{3!}$. We have $\frac{P(52,3)}{3!} = \binom{52}{3}$, not $\frac{P(52,3)}{3!} = \frac{\binom{52}{3}}{3!}$

Comment: is 52C3 is the right answer for different cards

Comment: @tarun8572 Yes. Actually in my answer, I kind of assume the cards are different. (If the cards weren't different, i.e., if we allow repetition, then I think... the answer is $(52)^3$ if order matters and then $(52)^3$ divided by something if order doesn't matter.)